# Problemas com Loop Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando a página *Category.php* e usando um *Custom Post Type* chamado *Pai*. Dentro desse *post type* tem algumas categorias: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. O que eu queria era que ao entrar na pagina da *categoria 4*, mostrasse apenas os *posts* dessa categoria, mas está mostrando todos os *posts* desse *Post Type*.

O *loop* que estou usando é esse:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pai',
); 

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

<p>Existe Posts</p>

endwhile;

else:

<p>Não Existe Posts...</p>

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Então eu não entendi

Comment: Deixa eu tentar te explicar o que eu preciso, em cada página das categorias ex: site.com/cat/2 eu preciso que mostre somente os posts dessa categoria e não de todas, que é o que está acontecendo com esse loop que eu mostrei.

Comment: Então, a resposta que falei funcionava... Você coloca a categoria que você quer por exemplo categoria 4 e aí será mostrado os posts da categoria 4

Comment: Sim, porém em todas as páginas vai mostrar os posts da categoria 4.

Comment: Já tentou filtrar os dados no `WP_Query` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters ?

Comment: Não funciona :( , Será que vou precisar fazer um arquivo categoria-1.php para cada uma das categorias? queria fazer tudo no arquivo category.php

Comment: Se você vai colocar somente post para tal categoria, da para você fazer relação entre elas

Comment: E como eu faço isso?